# UISplitViewController drag thumbnail onto detail view

Tags: ios

Is it possible to create an effect of dragging a thumbnail from the master view (collection of jpegs) onto the detail view, as if the jpeg is hovering across the boundary of both when you select and drag it across?  I have had a think about it and tried creating a view that encompasses both as a subview with a clear background but it seems theoretically unworkable.

Comment: You could add a subview in the app window, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Yes, put the view to be drug in the UISplitview's view instead of either the detail or master view controller.  Or, more precisely, move it to that view controller when you go to drag it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I don't have any code for it however the logic is

1. You should catch the tap event and get the image view  coordinates
2. Remove image view from superview and add it to a window(or a transparent view) don't forget the convert the coordinates to new superview
3. Move the image view  as touch moves and decide if the image view ended up in the details view
4. Remove image view from transparent view and add it to details view (preferably animated) again don't forget the convert the coordinates to new superview
5. clean up transparent view